# JavaScript: Is it necessary to escape diacritic characters on regex and objects?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, escaping, google-closure-compiler

I'm preparing some JavaScript files for production, and I'm trying to reduce their size as much as possible, I have the following function:

```
function toAscii(txt) {
  var map = {'á':'a','à':'a','â':'a','ã':'a','ä':'a','å':'a','è':'e','é':'e','ê':'e','ë':'e','ì':'i','í':'i','î':'i','ï':'i','ò':'o','ó':'o','ô':'o','õ':'o','ö':'o','ø':'o','ù':'u','ú':'u','û':'u','ü':'u'};
  return txt.replace(/[áàâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõöøùúûü]/g, function (m) {return map[m];}); 
}
```

But when I compile it with [Google Closure](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler), which is a good software, it unicode escapes the regular expression **and the object**.

```
function toAscii(a){var b={"\u00e1":"a","\u00e0":"a","\u00e2":"a","\u00e3":"a","\u00e4":"a","\u00e5":"a","\u00e8":"e","\u00e9":"e","\u00ea":"e","\u00eb":"e","\u00ec":"i","\u00ed":"i","\u00ee":"i","\u00ef":"i","\u00f2":"o","\u00f3":"o","\u00f4":"o","\u00f5":"o","\u00f6":"o","\u00f8":"o","\u00f9":"u","\u00fa":"u","\u00fb":"u","\u00fc":"u"};return a.replace(/[\u00e1\u00e0\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u00e5\u00e8\u00e9\u00ea\u00eb\u00ec\u00ed\u00ee\u00ef\u00f2\u00f3\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u00f8\u00f9\u00fa\u00fb\u00fc]/g,function(a){return b[a]})};
```

I've tested that the unescaped code works, so do you think is necessary to escape it?
I read it works because the HTML document has to be `<meta charset="utf-8">` which my case. But no matter what I try greek, arabic, chinese, `ISO-8859-7`, `GB2312`, `ASMO_449` it always works.

So why it's usually escaped? it's a browser dependent problem? would you leave it unescaped to reduce the file size?

---

PD: Maybe the problem is if at any point you use an editor to edit the JS file that does not have the right encoding, it would break the characters, is that right?
I don't think its worth to encode if that’s the only problem.

PD2: If I apply --charset utf-8 flag at closure-compiler software it does not escape the characters.

Comment: See the references to "encoding" and "charset" in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html. Non-UTF-8 encodings have variable support and might be deprecated (conflicting information on this) but the short answer is that you don’t really need to care. Use UTF-8 everywhere and it’ll work. No need to escape.

Comment: "*Google Closure, which is a good software*" - [citation needed]. In this case, it's either overcaucious or just didn't care about its output format. It might also be related to the age of closure compiler, which was created in a time when utf-8 was less ubiquitous.

Comment: "*I read it works because the HTML document*" - if those are external scripts, and you sound like they are, then no. Only the encoding of the script file itself matters, given by the HTTP headers.

Comment: @Bergi I have similar functions inside the HTML document and in extrental JS, so both. Nor the HTTP header of the Apache and Nginx Server I use send any "charset" for JS files, and according to this https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/#unicode-encoding-of-source-files it should fallback to the HTML charset.

Comment: @Bergi "[citation needed]" are you asking for Google Closure info? 
That it is a good software, is my personal opinion, it is the best JS compressor I tried.  
OK I got it, if I apply `--charset utf-8` flag at `closure-compiler` it does not escape the characters.  
I also tested, if I create a new file without declaring the UTF-8 encoding (`Notepad++`) it breaks the characters, I think there is where is most of the danger, on the developing side.

Answer (score 0):

The charset option is documented here:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options#miscellaneous

--charset VAL
Input and output charset for all files. By default, accept UTF-8 as input and output US_ASCII